# Motor of what type should I choose?

Tags: motor, servo, compass

I want to build something that behaves like a regular magnetic compass, but using this [electronic compass](http://wiki.seeed.cc/Grove-6-Axis_AccelerometerAndCompass_V2.0/) and some motor what will rotate the arrow pointing to the north.

So I think the motor must satisfy the following parameters:

1. 360 degree continuous rotation
2. Rotation to the specified angle

Motor of what type should I choose?

Comment: A continuous rotation servo.

Comment: A stepper motor would suffice if you were happy with their typical 200 step (or, possibly, 400 half-step) positional accuracy. On power-up you would have to reference the needle by rotating it (or an arm under the dial) until a home sensor is activated. You could make this into an attractive boot-up procedure as seen on some car dashboards where all the meters swing to full scale and back to zero when ignition is turned on.

Comment: @Transistor cool, I like your idea with boot-up calibration. Repost your comment as an answer

Comment: Really? Not that I am offended by my solution not chosen, but it is simpler and more appropriate by all means. BTW, the homing sequence is not a "cool feature" but a major annoyance.

Comment: @EugeneSh. your suggestion is ok too. I don't know what to choose now: servo or stepper.

Comment: Think in terms of number of code lines, mechanical and electrical design....

Comment: @EugeneSh. then servo wins.

Comment: @EugeneSh. But what about cost? I thought what servos are more expensive than steppers (for my project I need 4 motors, 2 of them must be able to do continuous rotation)

Comment: You need a really small one here, and these are pretty cheap (not sure about the quality you are looking for). Anyway, it is up to you to weight all of the pros and cons.

Comment: BTW, Why do you need it at all? Arrange a bunch of LEDs in a circle and make them point wherever you want (what is the required resolution?)...

Comment: @EugeneSh. This example with magnetic compass is just an example, I'm doing something like north oriented stabilizer

Comment: You know, this might change the proposed solutions drastically...

Comment: @EugeneSh. hm. Like that? I need to stabilize very tiny element, like compass pointer, so motor does not have to be powerful. I think magnetic compass is correct example

Comment: OK, you know your requirements, I guess. As a former developer of some stabilized systems I can tell you that we were using BLDCs with some pretty complex feedback control :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I will think more about my requirements, because there are multiple ways to do my project. Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servo motors that are continuous rotation are really just geared DC motors! As they have either been disconnected from the internal pot/ don't have an internal pot, you **can't specify an angle to which they move**, instead they just keep rotating! The only real option is a stepper motor with a counter in the program which stores the number of steps taken by the stepper motor, this can then be multiplied with the angle of rotation per step to find the total degrees rotated from start position.

**Implementation Idea:** You can 'Home' the stepper during boot by placing the magnetometer sensor on the arrow (or the rotating arm) itself! Thus it turns in one direction until it gets to north during boot and can function this way too! By turning to point north as the system is rotated!

Answer (score 0):

Use a servomotor if you need precise control, they have built in feedback.

Steppers do not, they are open loop so you can only say "step x amount of steps" so you'll need an exteral method to calibrate the position of the motor.

Servos can be commanded to a specific location and they will go there every time.

> Servomotors are generally used as a high-performance alternative to
>   the stepper motor. Stepper motors have some inherent ability to
>   control position, as they have built-in output steps. This often
>   allows them to be used as an open-loop position control, without any
>   feedback encoder, as their drive signal specifies the number of steps
>   of movement to rotate, but for this the controller needs to 'know' the
>   position of the stepper motor on power up. Therefore, on first power
>   up, the controller will have to activate the stepper motor and turn it
>   to a known position, e.g. until it activates an end limit switch. This
>   can be observed when switching on an inkjet printer; the controller
>   will move the ink jet carrier to the extreme left and right to
>   establish the end positions. A servomotor will immediately turn to
>   whatever angle the controller instructs it to, regardless of the
>   initial position at power up.

Source: Wikipedia Servomotor

Comment: I have mini servo, but it can't do 360 degree continuous rotation. Is there servos that can do this?

Comment: Yeah, usually they come in 360 or continuous flavours. You can mod some of the 360's to do continuous.

Comment: I read what then it will act like regular stepper motor and I will not to be able to choose angle like with my current servo

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56980/continuous-servo-position-control